# Discover+Request a Kafka Streams Instance on Kubernetes when ReplicaSet=2

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka-streams

How can I send a RPC request to another instance of the same *Kafka Streams* app instance on the same *Kubernetes* Service.

NOTE: This worked previously on Docker when exposing the current instances ip:port with the `application.server` property

e.g. `ReplicaSet=2`

StreamApp Instance 1 endpoint = *1.2.3.4:7079*

StreamApp Instance 2 endpoint = *1.2.3.5:7079*

I would like to send a rest request from Instance 1 accessing the remote Interactive Queries on Instance 2

**what I have tried already**

I sent a CURL request from instance 1 -> instance 2 : **but got a 404 error**

```
curl -X GET "http://1.2.3.5:7079/user/1" -H "accept: application/json"
```

but if I send the CURL request from K8 Host -> Instance 2 :**I get a 200 ok**

```
curl -X GET "http://1.2.3.5:7079/user/1" -H "accept: application/json"



 #values.yml
replicaCount: 1

 image:
  repository: "docker.hosted/steam-app"
  tag: "0.1.0"
  pullPolicy: Always
  pullSecret: "a_secret"

service:
 name: http
 type: NodePort
 externalPort: 7079
 internalPort: 7079

kafka:
 host: "kafka.default"
 port: "9092"

ingress:
 enabled: false
```

## deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "stream-app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "stream-app.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "stream-app.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_HOST
              value: "{{ tpl .Values.kafka.host . }}"
            - name: KAFKA_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.kafka.port }}"
            - name: MY_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: MY_POD_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.service.internalPort }}"
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/alive
              port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/ready
              port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
    {{- if .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml .Values.nodeSelector | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.image.pullSecret }
```

## service.yml

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "stream-app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "stream-app.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.externalPort }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
      protocol: TCP
      name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  selector:
    app: {{ template "stream-app.name" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

Comment: Your **instances 2** has different IP address, in examples. Is it ok?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi, yes , you can get these endpoints when you execute `kubectl get ep`

Comment: Could you provide a yaml files for the StreamApp instances Pods or Deployments? Kubernetes components do not give you 404 errors, but apps in pods do.

Comment: added the .yml, yes the 404 error is when the rest endpoint of the other pod instance  (2) cannot be found (by curl) from the current pod instance (1), these rest endpoints can be hit when I am executing them from the K8 master ssh console (with curl), so the host_ip+port+url seem to be correct.

Comment: Is this chart from the "stable" helm repository or you're using your own chart to install kafka?

Comment: That's a helm chart for a Microservice that uses the Kafka Streams API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled Istio injection before installing the service and then re enabled it after installing the service and now its all working fine, so the commands that worked for me were:

[image]